# Dynamic webpage content appears on top of Navigation Bar using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I wanted a Navigation Bar that is common across all webpages so I created `Header.html` and use `<?php include('Includes/Header.html') ?>` in all of my webpages to add the Nav Bar/Header to the top of each page.

However, when I try to add dynamic content to the body of a webpage (using PHP): the page content appears "on top" of the Nav Bar/Header and I can't work out why.

Here is the code for `Header.html`

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
        body 
        {
            margin:0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            background-attachment:fixed;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
            top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
        }

        li {
            float: left;
            border-right:1px solid #bbb;
        }

        li:last-child {
            border-right: none;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            background-color: #111;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
        }

        form 
        {
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }

        form input 
        {
           display: inline; 
        }

        .spacer
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 95px;
        }

        .answer {
            background-color:   #DCDCDC;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
      <li><a  href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="Search_Found_Items.php">Search Items</a></li>
      <li><a href="Report_Found_Item.php">Report Found Item</a></li>
        <li style="float: right; color: White">
            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
                {
                    echo "{$_SESSION['email']}";
                    echo " ";
                    echo "<a href='Logout.php'>Logout</a>";
                }else{
                    include('Includes/Login_Form.html');
                    echo "<a href='Register.php'>Register</a>";
                }
            ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the code for `Search.php` which is where the problem is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('Includes/Header.html');
    include('Item_List.php');
 ?>
```

Code for `Item_List.php`:

```
<?php
//connect to the database
try{
  $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=...;host=localhost", "...", "...");
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $rows = $db->query("SELECT Catagory, Colour, Found_Place, Found_Date FROM Item");
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>
<div class="item_div">
  <ul>
    <li><?= $row['Catagory'] ?></li>
    <li><?= $row['Found_Place'] ?></li>
    <li><?= $row['Found_Date'] ?></li>
    <li><?= $row['Colour'] ?></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

For some reason the content inside `Item_List.php` is rendered on top of the content of `Header.html`! I have tried adding the content of `Item_List.php` into the bottom of `Search.php` but the same thing happens. Adding lots of line breaks doesn't seem to work either. You can see what I mean by clicking the image link. Sorry the image is slightly unclear, but just above "Home, Search" etc there is a row of data that should be rendered below the navbar.

[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTQL5.png)

Please help I'm so confused!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by removing the following lines from your css code:

```
position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
```

However, you might want to look into using selectors (class, ID) for your navigation and content area.

Comment: Thank you :) Can't believe it was so simple as wrong CSS I was expecting something more technical and over my head

Comment: Glad it helped :-)